# Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop, I am getting this error in my react native app

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-hooks, react-native-flatlist

I  am getting the below errors when I tried to fetch array data from firebase firestore.
How can I solve this issue could someone please suggest me the code structure.

VM22 bundle.js:3927 Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.

Check the render method of `CellRenderer`. See https://reactjs.org/link/warning-keys for more information.
at http://localhost:19006/static/js/bundle.js:157320:19
at CellRenderer (http://localhost:19006/static/js/bundle.js:172017:36)

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import {View, Button, Text, FlatList, StyleSheet, Pressable, TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native'
import {firebase} from '../config';

const Testing = ({ navigation }) =>{
    const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);
    const todoRef = firebase.firestore().collection('testing');
  

    useEffect(() => {
        todoRef.onSnapshot(
            querySnapshot => {
                const users = []
                querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
                    const {  ArrayTesting
              
                    } = doc.data()
                    users.push({
                        id: doc.id,
                        ArrayTesting
                      
                    })
                })
                setUsers(users)
            }
        )
    }, [])
return (

   <View style={{ flex:1,}}>
   <FlatList 
 data={users}
  numColumns={1}
  renderItem={({item}) => (

    <Pressable >
<View>

  <View>
{ (item.ArrayTesting) 
  ? item.ArrayTesting.map((item) => <Text>{item}</Text>) 
  : <Text></Text>
}

</View>

</View>
 </Pressable>
     )} />
</View>
);}
export default Testing;
```

Comment: Please search your problem online before asking a question, this is a super common question that has already been asked and answered hundreds of times

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While you are mapping components in react, you have to provide unique key for the components, so it will know which component to rerender.

```
   <View>
{ (item.ArrayTesting) 
  // if item has unique field, please provide that as key in Text
  ? item.ArrayTesting.map((item,index) => <Text key={index}>{item}</Text>) 
  : <Text></Text>
}

</View>
```

Answer (score 1):

Hey flatlist already has a property called `keyExtractor` , please use that , so that all elements already have an unique key and you dont have to pass any explicitly to child comps :

```
<Flatlist
keyExtractor={(item, _index) => String(_index)}
/>
```

And also in your renderItem add the below :

```
 { (item.ArrayTesting) 
      ? item.ArrayTesting.map((item,index) => <Text key={index}>{item}</Text>) 
      : <Text></Text>
    }
```

Hope it helps, feel free for doubts

Comment: Sir please check the code-   it's not working
   <FlatList 
 data={users}
  numColumns={1}
  keyExtractor={(item, _index) => String(item?.id)}
  renderItem={({item}) => (
<Pressable >
<View>
<View>
{ (item.ArrayTesting) 
  ? item.ArrayTesting.map((item) => <Text>{item}</Text>) 
  : <Text>-none-</Text>
}

Comment: whats not working?

Comment: wait, you have a map inside flatlist too ? :O

Comment: Gaurav Sir, I am getting same issue it's not working. please check your suggested  code in the screenshot image- https://i.stack.imgur.com/OumAc.png

Comment: hello rahul, ive updated the answer , kindly check :)

Comment: Also please check firestore data- https://i.stack.imgur.com/BHiim.png

Answer (score 0):

The above answer is correct, however, I'd like to add a point of clarity that the answer above even touched on a bit. I'd like to emphasize it a bit more :).

When adding a key prop to each element (so that react knows how to keep track of them in the DOM), we should provide each `<Text />` component with a proper unique key.

This could be like an `id: 1` property returned on each object or data point from the server. This will ensure headaches of React misunderstanding your data since your `key`s are just ordered indexes. If ever your data changes (you update your list to remove one item) React might remove the wrong item do to shifting indexes.

```js
<View>
 {(item.ArrayTesting) 
   // if item has unique field, please provide that as key in Text
   ? item.ArrayTesting.map((item) => <Text key={item.id}>{item}</Text>) 
   : <Text></Text>
 }
</View>
```

Comment: Sir, it's not working I just tried it, I am getting same issue with your code

Comment: Well do you have an `id` property on your returned data? `id` was just an example, but if you don't return a property called `id` you can't use it. You would have to use whatever unique property you return on each item in your data.

Comment: Sir please check the image I am trying to fetch data from here- https://i.stack.imgur.com/BHiim.png

Comment: It appears you're simply returning an array of strings. If the strings (each text) you're returning is unique, you can use those strings. However, if not, you can use index. But you should really change your data to have a unique `id` from the server